# How to list security updates installed on a Ubuntu 10.04 server?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to list packages on a Ubuntu 10.04 server that were upgraded because of a security fix that was released. I tried running "apt-cache pkgnames" and "dpkg --get-selections" commands, but they list all the packages that are currently installed on the system. How do I get a list of security updates installed on a Ubuntu 10.04 system?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Amit